# Errorcode 2 in xml response

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

I am having a hard time with a treasury department server.

After sending xml it returns the following error

```
{"data":{"successful":false,"errorCode":"2","errorMessage":"IN PR_XAEFL.PR_XAEFLVLD AT STAGE: LOAD XML\r\n","formType":"RTN.IITPRM","taxYear":"2019","validationMessages":null,"links":null}}
```

This is the xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--REVISED 01.04.2019-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema" targetNamespace="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema">
```

This is the xml I am sending

```
<ns:PR482_2019 xmlns:ns="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema">
```

Nobody on the treasury programming department knows what this means

Any help will be highly appreciated

ariel

Comment: Can you share complete xsd ? Looks like you have just shared first line of it. Also, the xml you are sending is only one line ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and for asking.  I found the problem, is an escape character that I inadvertently place at the end of the file.  As soon as I pull it out, I got successful.

Sorry for the inconvenience.